# Sightly and cq:dropTargets

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm developing a new site using the latest AEM6 (formerly CQ). Originally you were able to drag images/videos into the components drop zone which was setup in the components dropTarget using JSP's.

But since Sightly templating is now the preferred way of building components rather than JSP's is it still possible to have dropTarget in Sighlty templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop target is [configured using node `cq:dropTargets`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/components.html#Configuring%20with%20cq:EditConfig%20Child%20Nodes) node under the `cq:editConfig` and it doesn't depend on the used markup language.

The only thing that markup has to produce is a `<div>` tag with class `cq-dd-CONFIGNAME` which will be used as a drop zone. Sightly can easily generate such markup (below example will show it only in the edit mode):

```
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" class="cq-dd-images">Drop image here</div>
```

Comment: are you able to have multiple dropTargets in one component? As I've tried to place 2 in the component each with a separate config name but every time I drag an image over both dropTarget values are updated to the same value.

Comment: Tom, it's hard to answer this in the comment field, so just ask a separate question on SO.

Comment: Tomek I've created a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185809/having-multiple-cqdroptargets-in-one-component

Comment: @TomekRękawek Is it possible to use in AEM6.5 both the path and the drag and drop for the video file? We would like the editors to be able to use the path selector as well as drag and drop when they select an MP4 file for the video component.