# Having multiple cq:dropTargets in one component

Tags: aem

I've managed to implement my single cq:dropTarget into my component with the following sightly code:

```
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" class="cq-dd-videoplayer" data-sly-text="Drop video here"></div>
```

And the cq:dropTargets is setup like so:

```
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <videoplayer
            jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
            accept="[video/.*]"
            groups="[media]"
            propertyName="./videoPath"/>
    </cq:dropTargets>
```

This works perfectly... The issue I'm having is having multiple cq:dropTargets in the one component. The issue I have is when I drop an asset into one of the cq:dropTargets both values in the dropTargets are updated with the same value.

This is my current setup:

Sightly:

```
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" class="cq-dd-videoplayer cq-video-placeholder cq-block-sm-placeholder md-dropzone-video" data-sly-text="Drop video here"></div>

    <div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" class="cq-dd-imageofplayer cq-video-placeholder cq-block-sm-placeholder md-dropzone-video" data-sly-text="Drop image here"></div>
```

cq:dropTargets

```
<cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <videoplayer
        jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
        accept="[video/.*]"
        groups="[media]"
        propertyName="./videoPath"/>
    <imageofplayer
        jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
        accept="[image/.*]"
        groups="[media]"
        propertyName="./imagePath"/>
</cq:dropTargets>
```

so now the ./videoPath and ./imagePath become the same value from the dragged in asset.

Answer (score 1):

On the 22nd of August 2015 has been released a new featurepack CQ-6.1.0-FEATUREPACK-6563 which solved this problem.
Related bugs fixed:
- CQ-39715 - Make multiple in-place editors smarter
- CQ-41631 - Can't place multiple fileupload widgets on the same dialog
- CQ-42676 - Inplace editing does not work for static included components

So now you need to create inside cq:inplaceEditing a node called cq:childEditors primaryType unstructured and inside that one node type cq:ChildEditorConfig for each element composed by two properties: "title" and "type" where title will be showed in a dropdown menu when you click on the edit link. I created a 3 columns image component and I can drag-and-drop images from the Content Finder for each of them.
[image: Custom dropdown menu]
Also the Configure section is working with 3 tabs where I can drag-and-drop/upload images for each of them.
[image: Configure section]
I suggest to use wcm/foundation/components/textimage as example.
References: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/multiple-inplace-editors.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to drop an image after video?
If so, just looking at your `cq:dropTargetConfig` for "imageofplayer",
according to [docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/edit_config.html),
`accept` property value should be `"Regex applied to the asset mime type to validate if dropping is allowed."`
So if you are trying to drop an image , it should be:

```
accept="[image/.*]"
```

Comment: sorry that's a typo, its not in my current code. - updated code example.